# Moz rendering height differently on element than Webkit

Tags: css, firefox

Trying to display an H3 on hover using the following CSS on this [site](http://mtthwbsh.com/sta499/home.html):

```
  a > h3 {
  min-width: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;

  a:hover > h3 {
  bottom: 0;
  }
```

For some reason this is not rendering the same in Firefox as it is in Chrome and Safari. When min-height is set to 100px it works fine in Chrome and Safari, when it is set to 50px it works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely because Firefox (as of ver. 20.0.1) still needs the `-moz` vendor prefix for the `box-sizing` property, just add:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Well that's one of those solutions that just slaps you in the face with obviousness. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Will do, waiting to clear the 10 minute mark per Stack's request.